# How to add text to modal on button click

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have this modal

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="bankAssess" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabelBank" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabelBank">Bank Assess <span id="bankAssessBondId"></span></h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form>
                           <div class="credit-scoring">
                                <label for="credit-scoring" class="form-control-label">Credit Scoring:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="credit-scoring">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-form-Bank">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and I would like to add text in `<span id="bankAssessBondId"></span>` when the following button is clicked

```
<button class="btn btn-success bank" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bankAssess" value="bond3">
Bank Assess
</button>
```

as I have multiple buttons for this, I'm using an EventListener as follows

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-success bank');
    for(var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++){
        buttons[i].on("click", function(){
             $('#bankAssessBondId').append($(this).value)
        })
}
```

but the 'click' button event is not detected. How can I fix this?

Comment: It would be good to have some more details, such as how those buttons are created - for example, if they're dynamically generated or populated from an ajax request then that style of event handler won't work...

Comment: yes, the buttons are created by an ajax request. I have a list of transactions each of which has one of those buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For elements that are dynamically generated you'll need to use the [delegated events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) form of the [JQuery on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function:

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn.btn-success.bank', function() {
    $('#bankAssessBondId').append($(this).value)
}
```

I've used "body" in this case as the parent element, but it could be any element that's a parent of the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue looks to be that you are trying to use the [jQuery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with an element that was discovered not using jQuery. The way I see it you have two possible solutions depending on what you are trying to achieve.

1. use the [addEventListener](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp)

   ```
   var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-success bank');
   for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
       buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
            $('#bankAssessBondId').append($(this).value)
       })
   }
   ```
2. use jQuery to select the buttons and use the .on function to apply a click listener to all items returned

   ```
   var buttons = $(".btn.btn-success.bank");

   buttons.on("click", () => {
       //do stuff here
   });
   ```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

When selecting an element with multiple classes then the selectors must be specified without spaces like below.

```
$('.btn.bank.btn-success')
```

Also in this, case the modal should be opened with the script as the span value inside modal needs to be changed dynamically.

```
$('#bankAssess').modal('toggle');
```

```js
$(function() {


  $('.btn.bank.btn-success').click(function() {

    var val = $(this).attr("value");

    console.log(val);

    $('#bankAssessBondId').append(val);
    $('#bankAssess').modal('toggle');

  });


});
```

```css
#bankAssessBondId {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="bankAssess" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabelBank" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabelBank">Bank Assess <span id="bankAssessBondId"></span></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="credit-scoring">
            <label for="credit-scoring" class="form-control-label">Credit Scoring:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="credit-scoring">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-form-Bank">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-success bank" type="button" data-target="#bankAssess" value="bond2">
Bank Assess
</button>

<button class="btn btn-success bank" type="button" data-target="#bankAssess" value="bond3">
Bank Assess
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the button by its class name using

```
$(".bank").on('click', function () {
  alert('clicked');
    $('#bankAssessBondId').append($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

Also append the value of the button to the id="bankAssessBondId"

```
<span id="bankAssessBondId"></span>
<button class="btn btn-success bank" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bankAssess" value="bond3">
Bank Assess
</button>
```

Using a sample of your code

Here is a working example.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oQGJOm